# Why couldn't I import np.typing.NDArray, but now I can?

Tags: python, numpy

I'm running into a weird situation with Python imports.
Does someone know how this works?

I have:

```
import numpy as np
values: Union[Sequence[int], np.typing.NDArray]
probs: Union[Sequence[float], np.typing.NDArray]
```

​Now that fails because np.typing can't be imported this way.  I guess since that is not defined in the [init file](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/main/numpy/__init__.py)?

Ok, so now I replace this with:

```
import numpy as np
import numpy.typing as npt
values: Union[Sequence[int], npt.NDArray]
probs: Union[Sequence[float], np.typing.NDArray]
```

​and now it works - but why doesn't it break on the 'probs' line? There, I still have the same statement that was giving me an error before. What changed to make this work?

*Context: Numpy 1.21.3, Python 3.7*

*Note: I know I can simply replace both statements, but I was surprised by why this doesn't give an error and wanted to know how this worked.*

Answer (score 1):

After you run import

```
import numpy.typing as npt
```

interpreter "find out" addition parts of np.

You can check this with:

```
import numpy as np
len(dir(np)) # 602 (in my case)

import numpy.typing as npt
len(dir(np)) # 604
```